# How to reference HTML from external webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I apologize in advance for the rudimentary question.

I have web page A that has a link to web page B on it. I need to locate the link to web page B (easy enough), and then store the HTML from web page B in a variable in my javascript script.

To store the HTML from web page A, I know it's a simple:

```
html_A = document.body.innerHTML;
```

How do I store the HTML from web page B? I believe I need to use AJAX correct? Or can I do it with javascript? And if it's the former, let's just assume the server for web page B allows for it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're open to using jQuery (which you've tagged), take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 3):

If youre trying to load HTML from a website that resides on a different server you will get a `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` Error. I dealt with this in the past and found a way to do it using YQL. Try it out:

```
//This code is located on Website A
$(document).ready(function() {
    var websiteB_url = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/page.html';
    var yql = '//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + websiteB_url + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(yql, function(data) {
        function filterDataCUSTOM(data) {
            data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');// no body tags
            data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, ''); // no linebreaks
            return data;
        }
        if (data.results[0]) {
            var res = filterDataCUSTOM(data.results[0]);
            $("div#results").html(res);
        } else {
            console.log("Error: Could not load the page.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yikes! Yahoo exposes that functionality? Any idea what they do for caching? Also, I'm not sure I understand your query. You specify the format as xml in the url but `getJSON` sets the format to Json (which is what you get back). Also you appened `&callback=?` which is used for jsonp, but you're clearly not using jsonp.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if web page B is on the same domain due to [the same-origin policy security feature of all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

If both pages *are* on the same domain you could do

```
$.get("/uri/to/webpage/b").then(function(html) {
     //do something with the html;
});
```

Note that the html will be available only once the ajax request finishes inside the `.then(...)` function. It will *NOT* be available on the line after this code block.

Hard to tell without knowing more about your situation but this is rarely the correct thing to do. You might want to look into [`$.fn.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (is limited by SOP) or using [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) (is not limited by SOP) as one of these might be more appropriate.

I should note that the standard way of doing this when you need access to html from another domain is to pull it down on your webserver and then re-serve it from there. That being said, it is probably a violation of that website's terms of use.

Comment: I agree. if you try to get a page from a different domain you will get an error like this: `Cross-Origin request blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at WEBSITE B. this can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS`