# serialize form getjson not working

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization, getjson

I want to get the serialized form values and pass that through a url with getJson. It worked fine but it stopped working somehow. It still works in IE but not in FF anymore. This is the code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#gui-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        var data = $("#gui-form :input").serialize();
        $.getJSON("https://test.com/process.php",data)
                  });
});
```

and in process.php i'll `$_GET` the values.

Comment: replace `$("#gui-form :input").serialize()` for  `$("#gui-form").serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `submit` method on your form, you can use the `$(this)` selector on jQuery to serialize the current form's inputs (assuming that all your HTML inputs have the `name` attributes set correctly). Try doing this:

```
$(function() {
        $('#gui-form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.getJSON("https://test.com/process.php", data, function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }));
        });
    });
```

Comment: i'm getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in Firefox. is there a workaround. something like httprequest? i'm not familiar with that

Comment: eek.. the good ol Cross Origin error. There is a workaround, hold on.

Comment: Take a look at this answer i gave someone in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461850/how-to-reference-html-from-external-webpage/28462168#28462168